# Changing Player Sprite through Shop

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a shop where you can buy a different player sprite from in-game currency. (The shop is a separate scene from the level) I was told that using scriptableobject is the way to go, so I made the following:

```
[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "New Sprite", menuName = "Player Sprites")]
public class PlayerSprites : ScriptableObject
{
    public string spriteName;
    public int cost;
    public Sprite sprite;
}
```

And I just added to the player script

```
public SpriteRenderer spriteRenderer;

void Start()
{
    spriteRenderer = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
}
```

I'm not really sure where to go from here... how to render the sprite on to the player from a different scene when the sprite button is pressed... Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though your question is quite *hazy* and I don't really see what you tried so far:

As you have it right now you will need one `ScriptableObject` for **each** `Sprite` item ... I don't think that's what you want. You should rather use one `ScriptableObject` storing the information of **all** `Sprite` items.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu(fileName = "Assets/New Store", menuName = "Sprites-Store")]
public class SpriteStoreContainer : ScriptableObject
{
    public List<StoreSpriteItem> SpriteItems = new List<StoreSpriteItem>();

    // you can/should also implement methods here as in any usual component!
}
```

Also make sure your `fileName` starts with `Assets/`

And a separate class for the Items which uses `[System.Serializable]` so you can display it in the Inspector.

```
using UnityEngine;

[System.Serializable]
public class StoreSpriteItem
{
    public string spriteName;
    public int cost;
    public Sprite sprite;
    public bool IsAvailable;

    // also here you could/should implement some methods e.g.
    public void BuyItem()
    {
        IsAvailable = true;
    }
}
```

And back in Unity:

1. Now you first have to `Instantiate` the `ScriptableObject` asset:
   Go to the Project View (Assets) -> <kbd>right mouse click</kbd> -> in the menu click on <kbd>Create</kbd> -> click on <kbd>Sprites-Store</kbd>
   [image]
   This should create a new asset called `New Store`(.asset) under `Assets`
   [image]
2. Now in the Inspector of this created asset you fill in the information you need. You should see our List `SpriteItems` with `Size = 0`. 
   [image]
   To create elements just increase the `Size` value and hit enter(Carefull: Unity doesn't ask if you change this value => take care you don't delete items by reducing this value accidently later)
   Now you can adjust all information for those SpriteItems
   [image]
3. Later wherever you need access to the information of this Asset you can just use the reference as any other Component => you can assign it e.g. via the Inspector using a public field e.g.

   ```
   using UnityEngine;

   public class ScriptThatUsesStore : MonoBehaviour
   {

       public SpriteStoreContainer Store;

       public void DoSomthingWithStore()
       {
           // example: just get the first List element
           Sprite someSprite = Store.SpriteItems[0].sprite;
       }
   }
   ```

   [image]
   and than access the data in it. Though I strongly recommend you rather implement some methods in the `ScriptableObject` like e.g. `BuyItem`, `GetSprite`, etc.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer! Helped a lot :)

Comment: Glad I could help!